# How to Make a Menu Sit to the Right of the Page - WordPress Theme Styling

Tags: css, menu, wordpress-theming

I'm sure there's a really obvious answer, but I've been trying to make the menu at the top of [this page](http://www.sculptcoach.com) sit to the right for hours.

Any thoughts on which element needs tweaking, or how to override the WP Theme's CSS?

```
/* Navigation Bar */

.nav-wrap {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #D9D9D9;
}
#navigation {
    float:center;
    margin:0 10px 0 10px;
}
#navigation ul li ul li a{
    font-weight:normal !important;
}
#navigation ul {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
#navigation ul li {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
#navigation ul li a {
    padding:0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-left:30px;
}
#navigation ul li:first-child a {
    margin:0 ;
}
.naviline {
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    left:12px;
    border-left:1px solid #D9D9D9;
}
#navigation ul li:first-child .naviline {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: "float:center" isn't a thing.

Comment: There are times when I really wish it was though.

Answer (score 4):

try

```css
#navigation {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 10px; /* same as 0 10px 0 10px */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the relative position and change the float center to float right?